# Show that $S^n \times S^n$ is not diffeomorphic to $S^{2n}$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

> Show that $S^n \times S^n$ is not diffeomorphic to $S^{2n}$

I know the prof using tools of algebraic topology but I try to show that using tools of differential topology I think in differential forms but I not sure, any hint or help I will be very grateful.

Comment: For $n=1$, one is parallelisable and the other one is not. Is this the type of proof you are after? Are you happy with using deRham cohomology?

Comment: You can use the higher homotopy groups $\pi_i(X)$. Since $\pi_i(S^n) = \{1\}$ if $ 1\leqslant i < n$, $\pi_n(S^n) = \Bbb Z$, and $\pi_(X\times Y) \simeq \pi_i(X)\oplus \pi_i(T)$, you can show the result

Comment: (of course, in my previous comment, one should replace $T$ with $Y$, but it is too late to edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show that $\Bbb S^{2n}$ and $\Bbb S^n\times\Bbb S^n$ are not homeomorphic. If so, they cannot be diffeomorphic, right?

Well suppose there’s a homeomorphism $f:\Bbb S^{2n}\to \Bbb S^n\times\Bbb S^n$ and recall that $\Bbb S^{2n}$ is the one-point-compactification of $\Bbb R^{2n}$. This means that, for any point $p\in \Bbb S^{2n}$, the space $\Bbb S^{2n}\setminus\{p\}\cong\Bbb R^{2n}$. Remove $f(p)$ from $\Bbb S^n\times\Bbb S^n$. Observe that $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism. Now observe that $\Bbb S^n\times \Bbb S^n\setminus \{f(p)\}$ is not contractible whereas $\Bbb R^{2n}$ is contractible. This leads to a contradiction and hence $f$ cannot be a homeomorphism.

Comment: you know one book to read the proof of that $(S^n \times S^n )\setminus \{x\}$ is not contractible?